# Java NIO (java.nio.*) - which version?

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html.  I thought this would be an easy compile with "javac WatchDir.java" - no dice.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O says NIO was introduced in J2SE 1.4.  I tried  5 & 6, still no joy!  ???  What am I missing here?

Comment: Define 'no dice' and 'no joy'. You can't seriously expect help after providing as little information as that.

Comment: WatchDir uses NIO2, which is introduced in Java 7

Answer (score 2):

The [`WatchDir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) example uses [`java.nio.file`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package, which is only available from Java 7.